# Set Height and Width for images as WPF background

Tags: wpf

I need to set a image as background for WPF Window. I have set it like that:

```
<Window x:Class="DiagramView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="418" Width="1185" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/Med.jpg" ></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
</Window>
```

But If I have height and width for window as orginal image, the image at window isn't not sharpen as it should be. I guess it happens because part of height and width is taken by window itself. What I properties I should use to have images with orginal width/height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to retain the original image size set the `Stretch` property to `None`:

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/Med.jpg" Stretch="None" />
</Window.Background>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the [`ImageBrush` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, you'll see that there are a number of properties that you can use to position the image within the `Brush`. The following are of particular interest for positioning:

AlignmentX
AlignmentY
Stretch
Viewbox
ViewboxUnits
Viewport
ViewportUnits

Please see the linked page for their descriptions.